# Haxe 3.2 javascript package names

Tags: javascript, package, haxe

I'm working on upgrading a project from haxe 2.10 to haxe 3.2 having previously done a similar upgrade from haxe 2.10 to 3.1.3.

However there is a new complication since the project interfaces with haxe compiled javascript from pure javascript.

Previously a class Test with "package name1.name2" would result in javascript code that had the full name "name1.name2.Test";

Since haxe 3.2 however this same code now yields

name1_name2_Test

Is this really intended and why ?

It's really annoying to debug all the places where it's wrong ..

Answer (score 4):

Currently, Haxe/JS package and class names are indeed "flattened" by default. It's a micro-optimization, I guess to make less object allocations and less name lookups.

You can disabled this feature by adding the `js-unflatten` flag to your compilation command, for example:

```
haxe -D js-unflatten -js out.js -main Main
```